# How to create ecommerce product price measure calculator using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, e-commerce, price

This code format I have found from one answer, and this is beneficial. But I need some modifications here. I am a new learner of javascript, and I want to add some quantity range here.  I want different prices when the quantity is increased. Here you can see the different "sizes" and different "side & color". For example: if the regular price is $38.4 for 1 quantity then, when the quantity is 10 to 24 I want the total cost should calculate the price at $9.71/quantity. What is the way to do it? Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Build Your Bodycare</h2>
  <form action="insertlabel.php" id="privtelabel" method="POST">
        Size:
        <select name='product' id='product' required>
          <option value="18X24">18"X24"</option>
          <option value="12X18">12"X18"</option>
          <option value="12X24">12"X24"</option>
          <option value="16X24">16"X24"</option>
          <option value="24X24">24"X24"</option>
          <option value="24X32">24"X32"</option>
          <option value="24X36">24"X36"</option>
          <option value="24X48">24"X48"</option>
        </select>
    
        <br><br> Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" id='quantity' required> 
        <br><br>Side & Color:
        <select name='size' id='size' required>
          <option value="1-Side 1-Color">1-Side 1-Color</option>
          <option value="1-Side 2-Color">1-Side 2-Color</option>
          <option value="2-Side 1-Color">2-Side 1-Color</option>
          <option value="2-Side 2-Color">2-Side 2-Color</option>
          <option value="1-Side Full-Color">1-Side Full-Color</option>
          <option value="1-Side Full-Color">1-Side Full-Color</option>
        </select>
        
        <p>(Sizes are only for soaps.)</p>
        Price: <span id="totalCost"></span>

    </form>

    <script>
        //Store some references to our DOM elements
        var productEl = document.querySelector('#product');
        var quantityEl = document.querySelector('#quantity');
        var sizeEl = document.querySelector('#size');
        var totalCostEl = document.querySelector('#totalCost');

        //Add the change event handlers on the applicable elements
        productEl.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);
        quantityEl.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);
        sizeEl.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);

        //Store your data in an object literal (essentially creating a map)
        var product_price = {}; //Noticed I replaced the [] with {}
        product_price['18X24'] = 5;
        product_price['12X18'] = 6;
        product_price['12X24'] = 6;
        product_price['16X24'] = 7;
        product_price['24X24'] = 8;
        product_price['24X32'] = 8;
        product_price['24X36'] = 10;
        product_price['24X48'] = 15;

        var size_price = {};   //Noticed I replaced the [] with {}
        size_price['1-Side 1-Color'] = 0;
        size_price['1-Side 2-Color'] = 2;
        size_price['2-Side 1-Color'] = 3;
        size_price['2-Side 2-Color'] = 5;
        size_price['1-Side Full-Color'] = 5;
        size_price['2-Side Full-Color'] = 5;


        //Here's our single event handler - called when any of the 3 elements fire a 'change' event
        function calculateTotal() {
        //console.log()
        var unitCost = product_price[productEl.value];
        var additionalCost = size_price[sizeEl.value] || 0;
        var qty = quantityEl.value || 0;

        totalCostEl.textContent = `Total cost: $${(unitCost * qty) + additionalCost}`;
        }
    </script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not completely clear what you want but I think you want to depend the price per item on the quantity. There are several ways to do it. Is the discount the same for all products? You could use some if else statements but maybe a switch statement is better.

Comment: Let me clear this for you, I want to put a price range depending on quantity, like if someone chooses quantity between 10 to 24 there will be a charge of $5 on each quantity but the regular price is $38.4. This $5 on each quantity will be applicable only when someone chooses quantity between 10 to 24. I will go for such a price range up to 1000. 10-24, 25-49,50-99, 100-249, 250-499, 500-999. For each quantity range here the price per quantity will be different. Just exactly like I mention for 10-24 quantity. Thank you.

Comment: Ah ok. But if this charge is the same for all products, and the number of cases (the quantity ranges like 10 - 24) is limited than it very easy to accomplish with a switch statement in your calculateTotal function.

Comment: No, the charge is not the same. The charge will be different. I am going to charge $9.71 between 10-24 quantity, $7.71 for 25-49 quantity, and so one. Every quantity rang will have a different charge.

Comment: Ok, that's not what I meant. I understand you want to charge different prices for different quantity ranges. But are the charges different for the quantity rangers for the different product. So is charge $9.71 for 10-24 for product X also $9.71 for 10-24 for product Y?

Comment: Yes, it would be a different price with different products. Not the same price. Every quantity will have a different charge and also every product will have a different charge. Here you can see some size, for example when any customer selects 18X24 and 1 side 1 color the price could be $38.4, but if the customer selects 18X24 with 1 side 2 colors the price will be another one. How can I do it?

Comment: Hmm, it is more a data structure/ database problem. I think I would choose for changing the product_price "table". Something like this:  ```product_price['18X24'] =  { 1-10: 5, 10-24: 7, etc  }``` Where the key is the quantity range and the value the price for that range.

Comment: I tried your formula, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my solution a bit. Instead of, for instance, `{0-10: 6, 10-24: 7}` I turned it into `{9 : 6, 24 : 7 }`. So I can check the quantiy. I added an if else statement but that is easily turned into a switch statement for all the different ranges. I just added the first two ranges.

```js
//Store some references to our DOM elements
var productEl = document.querySelector('#product');
var quantityEl = document.querySelector('#quantity');
var sizeEl = document.querySelector('#size');
var totalCostEl = document.querySelector('#totalCost');

//Add the change event handlers on the applicable elements
productEl.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);
quantityEl.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);
sizeEl.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);

//Store your data in an object literal (essentially creating a map)
var product_price = {}; //Noticed I replaced the [] with {}
product_price['18X24'] = {
  9: 5,
  24: 6
};
product_price['12X18'] = {
  9: 6,
  24: 8.24
};
product_price['12X24'] = {
  9: 6,
  24: 7.45
};
product_price['16X24'] = {
  9: 7,
  24: 8.14
};
product_price['24X24'] = {
  9: 8,
  24: 9.24
};
product_price['24X32'] = {
  9: 8,
  24: 10.99
};
product_price['24X36'] = {
  9: 10,
  24: 11.99
};
product_price['24X48'] = {
  9: 15,
  24: 17.00
};

var size_price = {}; //Noticed I replaced the [] with {}
size_price['1-Side 1-Color'] = 0;
size_price['1-Side 2-Color'] = 2;
size_price['2-Side 1-Color'] = 3;
size_price['2-Side 2-Color'] = 5;
size_price['1-Side Full-Color'] = 5;
size_price['2-Side Full-Color'] = 5;


//Here's our single event handler - called when any of the 3 elements fire a 'change' event
function calculateTotal() {
  //console.log()


  var additionalCost = size_price[sizeEl.value] || 0;
  var qty = quantityEl.value || 0;

  var price;

  if (qty < 10) {
    price = product_price[productEl.value][9]
  } else if (qty >= 10) {
    price = product_price[productEl.value][24]
  }

  totalCostEl.textContent = `Total cost: $${(price * qty) + additionalCost}`;
}
```

```html
<h2>Build Your Bodycare</h2>
<form action="insertlabel.php" id="privtelabel" method="POST">
  Size:
  <select name='product' id='product' required>
    <option value="18X24">18"X24"</option>
    <option value="12X18">12"X18"</option>
    <option value="12X24">12"X24"</option>
    <option value="16X24">16"X24"</option>
    <option value="24X24">24"X24"</option>
    <option value="24X32">24"X32"</option>
    <option value="24X36">24"X36"</option>
    <option value="24X48">24"X48"</option>
  </select>

  <br><br> Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" id='quantity' required>
  <br><br>Side & Color:
  <select name='size' id='size' required>
    <option value="1-Side 1-Color">1-Side 1-Color</option>
    <option value="1-Side 2-Color">1-Side 2-Color</option>
    <option value="2-Side 1-Color">2-Side 1-Color</option>
    <option value="2-Side 2-Color">2-Side 2-Color</option>
    <option value="1-Side Full-Color">1-Side Full-Color</option>
    <option value="1-Side Full-Color">1-Side Full-Color</option>
  </select>

  <p>(Sizes are only for soaps.)</p>
  Price: <span id="totalCost"></span>

</form>
```